# Sorting after Repartitioning PySpark Dataframe

Tags: sorting, pyspark, partition

We have a giant file which we repartitioned according to one column, for example, say it is `STATE`. Now it seems like after repartitioning, the data cannot be sorted completely. We are trying to save our final file as a text file but instead of the first state listed being Alabama, now California shows up first. `OrderBy` doesn't seem to have an effect after running the repartition.

```py
df = df.repartition(100, ['STATE_NAME'])\
    .sortWithinPartitions('STATE_NAME', 'CUSTOMER_ID', 'ROW_ID')
```

Comment: Passing a _list_ to `repartition` is not in accordance with the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html).

Comment: Ooops. OK same question for this code: df = df.repartition(100, 'STATE_NAME')\
    .sortWithinPartitions('STATE_NAME', 'CUSTOMER_ID', 'ROW_ID')

Comment: how many files are you going to save? 1 or 100?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a clear statement in the documentation about this, only this hint for [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html):

> The resulting `DataFrame` is hash partitioned.

Obviously, `repartition` doesn't bring the rows in a specific (namely alphabetic) order (not even if they were ordered previously), it only groups them. That `.sortWithinPartitions` imposes no global order is no wonder considering the name, which implies that the sorting only occurs *within* the partitions, not on them. You can try `.sort` instead.

Comment: I tried using .sort as well but it's the same results as orderBy